# How can I zip a folder via `archive_file` Terraform

Tags: terraform

I am using terraform to zip a folder as below code.

```
data "archive_file" "src" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "dist"
  output_path = ".build/src.zip"
}
```

It creates the zip file `src.zip` in `.build` directory. But the `src.zip` doesn't include the root folder which is `dist`. How can I zip the folder include the folder itself?

Comment: What you want to achieve is not yet implemented.
Please keep tracking the following PR and issue on Terraform Archive Provider Github repo to know when a solution to your problem is available:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-archive/pull/125
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-archive/issues/96
In the meantime Dan's answer is an acceptable workaround.

Answer (score 1):

So currently you're zipping a folder structure that looks like this:

```
dist
    ...
```

Is there anything stopping you from zipping a folder structure that looks like this?

```
my_archive_file_target
    dist
        ...
```